# How would i Unorder a Mobile page Nav Bar?

Tags: css, html, web, responsive-design

So i have a Mobile website in which the navigation Bar is ordered and the hover over background color is not proportionate to the design and looks terrible when one clicks and i would like to center it without having to mess the code up.

Here is how it looks now:
[image]

I tried to modify the code and took away the float: left to a None and then the nav seems to scramble.

Here is the mobile CSS code:

```
       .mainBanner nav{
position: absolute;
/*text-align: center;*/
   top: 15%;
   left: 15%;
font-size: 1.190em;
font-weight: bold;
height: 40px;
line-height: 30px;
margin: 0 auto 30px 50px; 
font-family: 'lato-Reg', sans-serif;

    }

    .mainBanner nav ul {
   list-style: none; 
   margin: 0 auto;
     }

    .mainBanner nav ul li {
float: left; 
display: inline; 
    }
  .mainBanner nav a:link, .mainBanner nav a:visited {
color: #ecf0f1; /* Color of the font in the nav*/ 
display: inline-block;
height: 30px;
padding: 5px 30px;
text-decoration: none;
     }
  .mainBanner nav a:hover, .mainBanner nav a:active,
  .mainBanner nav .active a:link, .mainBanner nav .active a:visited {
background: #16a085;
color: #fff;
border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
text-shadow: none !important;
    }
```

Comment: can you also add your HTML, maybe create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

update your code with this lets see

```
//comment this line
.mainBanner nav ul li {
    /*float: left; */
    display: inline; 
}

//uncomment this line
.mainBanner nav{
   text-align: center;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/isaacrajaei/V8xap/2/)

Comment: Your link is no good. You just linked to the main site, not a specific fiddle. Also, please always include the code from jsfiddles in the answer (or question, as the case may be), rather than just posting a link which isn't guaranteed to always be available.

Comment: Isaac Rajaei, It did'nt work, I used text-align: center; and didnt work, Been figuring this out for like 2 days already :(